# Compiling boost on Sunos

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, sunos, sunstudio

I have just started with using boost libraries.
For one of our projects i want to compile Boost 1.39.0 on Sun OS using sun compiler. However if i compile it using steps mentioned in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html, not all of the targets are compiled. Can someone provide resources which would be helpful for compiling it on Sun os. Are there any separate set of instructions for compiling on Sun OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SunOS compiler is notorious for not having conformant libraries and compilation. But we do have at least one tester that uses the platform (see [Sandia-sun tester](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/trunk/developer/summary.html)). And from what you can see there are many failures in the toolset. As for setting it up the key thing to do is not use the standard STD lib, but use the STLport STD lib. As you can see from the description of the setup of the Sandia-sun tester (see [Sandia-sun info](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/trunk/Sandia-sun.html)). What you can do is try and mirror that setup. First would be to create a user-config.jam that has the "using sun ..." part of that setup. And when you build you should build with something similar to: bjam sun-5.10 stdlib=sun-stlport address-model=64 .